# Vue.js: Why is my Single File Component not being rendered/displayed in my template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am currently learning how to build a web app using Vue.js. I have used the vue-cli (version 3.8.2), to scaffold a HelloWorld application.

I have modified the generated `HelloWorld.vue` component as follows:

#### /path/to/vue-app/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
        <b-tabs content-class="mt-3">
            <b-tab title="module1" active>
                <Module1/>
            </b-tab>
        </b-tabs>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Module1 from './Module1.vue';

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop() private msg!: string;
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

#### /path/to/vue-app/src/components/Module1

```
<template>
    <div class="module1">
        Module1
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Module1 extends Vue {
}    
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

#### /path/to/vue-app/src/router.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Home from './views/Home.vue';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue'),
    },
  ],
});
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/` The contents of my module `Module1` is not being displayed on the page.

Why is the component not being rendered (displayed), and how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must register your `Module1` component before use it (it's weird you didn't get any error).
In typescript you have to register components inside the `@Component` decorator, like this:

```
@Component({
  components: {
    Module1
  }
})
```

Comment: Which source file does this code segment go into? Module.vue or HelloWorld.vue?

Comment: Inside the parent component, or if you plan to use the component globally you can register the component inside the main.ts